# Python beginner looking for feedback on simple dice game

Tags: python

**Dice "Game"**

So, just started python a weeks time ago, so I'm looking for feedback/critique on things i can do to improve my code. I wrote a little user/pc dice rolling game. Any feedback at all is appreciated!

```
def dice(n: int) -> tuple:
    """
    Simple function to roll 'n' number of dices.
    Returns numbers of each roll and a total.

    :param n: number of dices to roll
    :return: dices_numbers, total
    """
    numbers = []
    total = 0
    for dices in range(n):
        number = random.randint(1, 6)
        numbers.append(number)
        total += number
    dices_numbers = ", ".join(map(str, numbers))
    return dices_numbers, total


def dice_check(user_total: int = 0, pc_total: int = 0) -> None:
    """
    Function to check whether user or pc won dice roll.

    :param user_total: user's total roll
    :param pc_total:  pc's total roll
    :return: None
    """
    if user_total > pc_total:
        print("Congratulations! You won")
    elif user_total < pc_total:
        print("Sorry, BOT wins!")
    else:
        print("Tie!")


number_of_dices = ""
user_roll = ""
pc_roll = ""
while True:
    number_of_dices = int(input("How many dices would you like to roll?"
                                " (0 to quit) >"))
    if number_of_dices == 0:
        break
    else:
        user_roll = dice(number_of_dices)
        pc_roll = dice(number_of_dices)
        print(f"You: Roll: {user_roll[0]}, a total of: {user_roll[1]}")
        print(f"BOT: Roll: {pc_roll[0]}, a total of: {pc_roll[1]}")
        dice_check(user_roll[1], pc_roll[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path in putting most of your code inside of functions.
I encourage you to go the full distance and make it your standard habit.
The code below does that by creating a `main()` function.

Python has a built-in `sum()` function, so your `dice()` and `dice_check()`
functions are probably doing more work than they need to. That's not a big
deal. Sometimes when you are learning, doing things the *hard way* can be
educational. In any case, the edited code below will illustrate how `sum()`
could simplify the situation.

The `dice()` function can be shortened substantially using a tuple
comprehension, if you want. You could also consider simplifying all downstream
code by bundling the dice roll and their sum into a small object. In this
example, something very simple like a `namedtuple` might be a good choice.
Notice how this change simplifies the return type of `dice()` and also cleans
up code that has to use its return value. Notice also that this decision has
the unanticipated benefit of allowing us to directly compare the `user` and
`pc` dice rolls to determine the winner. This works because the `total`
attribute is placed first within the `namedtuple`.

You already have a good suggestion to add some validation to the user input. By
shifting the collection of user input to its own function, you can keep
`main()` focused on overall program orchestration. A general guideline is to
keep detailed computation out of a script's `main()`. That function is almost always
the hardest to test in more complex programs, so you should get into the habit
of keeping it algorithmically simple. That thinking is behind the
`get_result()` function: let some other piece of code determine the winner and
handle the grubby task of assembling whatever message should be printed.

For brevity in this example, I dropped most of the printing (you should enhance
as needed) and the docstrings (its a good idea to retain them in the real
program).

```
import random
import sys
from collections import namedtuple

Roll = namedtuple('Roll', 'total roll')

def main(args):
    while True:
        # Get N of dice from user or quit.
        n = get_user_input()
        if not n:
            break
        # Roll dice.
        user = dice(n)
        pc = dice(n)
        # Report.
        msg = get_result(user, pc)
        print(msg)

def get_user_input() -> int:
    while True:
        prompt = 'How many dice would you like to roll? '
        reply = input(prompt).strip()
        try:
            return int(reply) if reply else 0
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass

def dice(n: int) -> Roll:
    roll = tuple(random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n))
    return Roll(sum(roll), roll)

def get_result(user, pc) -> str:
    winner = (
        'You' if user > pc else
        'Bot' if pc > user else
        'Tie'
    )
    return f'Winner: {winner} {user} {pc}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new as well, but I like to create an exception whenever I try to convert user input to an integer. Something like this-

```
while True:
    try:
        number_of_dices = int(input("How many dices would you like to roll?"
                                    " (0 to quit) >"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number.")
```

Comment: Will add that! thanks for the input :)